# Facebook Social Comments--limited visibility for any comments not posted to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

We are considering adding Facebook's "Social Comment" boxes to virtually every page of content on our site.

We're willing to allow unmoderated comments via the "Social Comment" plugin, but the "tit-for-tat" that we would ask of commenters is that they will also post their comment to their wall.

Right now the "Social Comment" plugin that Facebook provides allows the user to decide if they will post their comment to their Facebook wall.  If they uncheck the "Post to Facebook" box, their comment will appear only on the page they are commenting on, and not on their wall.

We would like any users who choose this option to have their comment set to "limited visibility."  Or, better yet, to simply be required to post the comment to their wall in order to post that comment to our site.

Are either of these possible?  I haven't been able to figure out a way to do either.

Another option we've explored (and not had any success with) is making all comments default to "Limited Visibility."  Then we would programmatically check for comments that were also posted to a user's wall, and make those comments available.  But so far, I have not been able to programmatically determine if a particular comment was posted to the author's Facebook wall or not.

Thanks!

-Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be "you can't do this."  :-(